# Failed to load class [javax.servlet.Filter] Cannot lower version of Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-migration

I have a spring project that I updated to version 3.  I added Jakarta to replace Javax.
When I run the application I get a `Failed to load class [javax.servlet.Filter]` error. Some of the post on Stack recommend lowering the version of Tomcat, but I have to keep it at 10.1.11.

When I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` I see that javax is being used by `kogito-spring-boot-starter` which is at version 1.41 which is the latest release and javax is also being used by s`pring-cloud-starter-security` which is at the latest release 2.2.5.

I am using Maven.
How would I fix this?

Comment: This will sound kinda dumb but have you simply tried to exclude those dependencies since you are using maven and add those specific dependencies ( jakarta.servlet.Filter )?
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions
As for lowering Tomcat, you are correct, Spring 6 requires Tomcat 10, 9 will not work.
Let me know if this helps Aaron.